# Github Actions - Best way to move files for commit from one branch to another

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a Github workflow that is meant to deploy to a test repository (that gets published via pages) from a dev branch. This is meant to work by:

- checking out the dev branch
- building packages, putting them in the appropriate test repo directory (this is handled in the referenced `update-test-repositories.sh`)
- committing the files to a specific "updating test repos" branch
- then creates a PR to get them into main, where when merged they are picked up and served on Pages by a separate workflow.

However, it seems that when committing the "updating test repos" branch in the "Commit new repo files" step, it brings along all commits from the dev branch getting deployed, and not just the new repo files. This is obviously counter productive.

Is there a way to update the files rather than pulling in the commits I would rather keep in the branch? Am I playing with branches correctly here? (I currently have the `git-auto-commit-action` creating the branch if not present, does that create the branch from main or the current branch?)

My workflow:

```yaml
name: Deployment - Repos - Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  workflow_call:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: [ "**" ]
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: "utilities"
jobs:
  deployToTestRepos:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: sudo apt-get install -y curl dpkg-dev
        
      - name: Setup Signing Key
        uses: crazy-max/ghaction-import-gpg@v6
        with:
          gpg_private_key: ${{ secrets.OQM_GPG_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.OQM_GPG_KEY_PASS }}
          
      - name: Update Test Repo Files
        run: ./update-test-repositories.sh
        
      - name: Commit new repo files
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5
        with:
          commit_message: Updated Repositories after release
          branch: 'update-test-repos-staging-${{ github.ref_name }}'
          create_branch: true
          push_options: '--force'
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const { repo, owner } = context.repo;
            const pulls = await github.rest.pulls.list({
              owner: owner,
              repo: repo,
              head: 'update-test-repos-staging-${{ github.ref_name }}',
              base: 'main',
              state: 'open',
            });

            if (pulls.data.length < 1) {
              await github.rest.pulls.create({
                title: '[Delpoy - Repos - Test] Update test repo files for branch ${{ github.ref_name }}',
                owner: owner,
                repo: repo,
                head: 'update-test-repos-staging-${{ github.ref_name }}',
                base: 'main',
                body: [
                  'This PR is auto-generated by',
                  '[actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script)',
                ].join('\n'),
              });
            } else {
              const existingPR = pulls.data[0];
              await github.rest.pulls.update({
                owner: owner,
                repo: repo,
                pull_number: existingPR.number,
                body: [
                  existingPR.body,
                  `Updated by Job ${context.job}`,
                ].join('\n'),
              });
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

To ensure only the relevant changes for the test repo are included, consider the following:

1. Isolate Changes for Test Repo: Ensure `update-test-repositories.sh` script only modifies files relevant to the test repository. It's important that this script doesn't inadvertently modify other project files.
2. Commit Only Relevant Changes: When you run `git-auto-commit-action`, it commits the changes present in the working directory. If `update-test-repositories.sh` script only changes files relevant to the test repo, then this shouldn't be a problem. However, if there are other changes in your working directory (from the `dev` branch), they will also be included in the commit.
3. Creating a Clean Branch: You might consider a strategy where you create a clean branch from main, then cherry-pick or apply only the changes made by `update-test-repositories.sh`. This would involve more complex scripting and might be done outside of `git-auto-commit-action`.

If I get it right, I suggest the following changes to your workflow (double check if applicable).
Firstly, switch the base branch for the new branch and if possible, checkout `main` before running the `git-auto-commit-action`. This way, the `update-test-repos-staging` branch will be based on `main`, and you only add the changes made to the test repos.

```
- name: Checkout main branch
  if: github.ref_name != 'main'
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    ref: main

- name: Apply Changes to Test Repos
  if: github.ref_name != 'main'
  run: # Script to apply changes from dev to the working directory
```

Also, be cautious with dynamic branch naming (`update-test-repos-staging-${{ github.ref_name }}`). This can create multiple branches for different feature branches in `dev`. Make sure this aligns with your workflow.

This should avoid the issue of carrying over all changes from dev.